# How to display image after upload in php Handle AJAX request on the Same Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create an image cropping tool, it should upload a pic, crop it and print it on the page as a image.png not as a base 64 (data:image) As I know it cannot be done through HTML and javascript. So I was trying to do this through PHP. I'm uploading and croping the image but I can't display the uploaded image, when I crop the image it creates two .png files. one of them normal image, second of them 0 byte error image (and every time when page refreshes it creates this 0 byte error image).

How can I fix it?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PHP and jQuery - Crop Image and Upload using Croppie plugin</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.js"></script>

  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="max-height: 500px;">
    <div class="card-header bg-info">PHP and jQuery - Crop Image and Upload using Croppie plugin</div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div id="upload-demo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding:5%;">
        <strong>Select image to crop:</strong>
        <input type="file" id="image">

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-upload-image" style="margin-top:2%">Upload Image</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="preview-crop-image" style="background:#9d9d9d;width:300px;padding:50px 50px;height:300px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


var resize = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    enableOrientation: true,    
    viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        type: 'circle' //square
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }
});


$('#image').on('change', function () { 
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      resize.croppie('bind',{
        url: e.target.result
      }).then(function(){
        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});


$('.btn-upload-image').on('click', function () {
  resize.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
  }).then(function (img) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {"image":img},
      success: function (data) {
        html = '<img src="' + img + '" />';
        $("#preview-crop-image").html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});


</script>
<?php
{
if(isset($_POST['image'])){

$image = $_POST['image'];
list($type, $image) = explode(';',$image);
list(, $image) = explode(',',$image);

$image = base64_decode($image);
$image_name = time().'.png';
file_put_contents('uploads/'.$image_name, $image);

echo 'successfully uploaded';
            display_image();
}
 function display_image(){
  ?>
  
    <img src="<?php echo "uploads/". $image_name; ?>" width="70" height="70" >

  <?php
  }
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your php code is executing on EVERY page request. That means that $_POST['image'] is empty on GET requests. Consider checking if the $_POST['image'] exists. The image is problably not showing because you are using $image_name when uploading and $image['name'] when loading the image in <img>

Comment: Hi, now it does not create a 0-byte image with each refresh, but it still does not display an image

Comment: Have you checked the upload folder and seen that the image has been uploaded?